# PageSpeed Insight -- Avoid enormous network payloads - Duplicate assets

Tags: lighthouse, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I'm trying to improve my PSI scores, and one of the biggest problems I have right now is the "Avoid enormous network payloads" part. Mainly, when I view details, there are duplicate files.

[duplicate files log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okroD.png)

Comment: So have you checked the network tab to ensure that these assets aren't loaded twice? At the moment there isn't enough information to help, do you have a publicly available URL we can look at where this happens?

Comment: the website is https://tymeinc.com/

thanks in advance!